# What does "provocative fictions" mean? Are they one kind of fiction?

Tags: meaning

I see this phrase in such sentence"The world knows his name, knows his reputation as the prolific author of provocative fictions, novels that..." But i wonder whether "provacative fiction"is a type of fictions and what does it mean.

Comment: So if i need to paraphrase "provacative fictions, novels", can i say "long and short novels(or fiction and non-fiction novels) with provoking thoughts"?

Comment: Fiction can be defined as works of the imagination (usually in the form of prose rather than poetry, though there are exceptions to this generalization) that chiefly use the written word to tell a story. This includes novels, novellas and short stories. A novel therefore belongs in the category of *fiction*, not *non-fiction*. Poetry is usually considered to comprise a separate category.

Comment: Whether a work of fiction can be considered to be *provocative* is partly a subjective judgment on the part of the reader (e.g. does it generate a significant shift in the reader's assumptions or provide them with useful new insights?), and partly on the author's explicit intent. For instance, is the author writing about a subject that is generally regarded as taboo in their society, or raising a societal issue that they think is being ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, 'fictions' is simply a shorthand way of saying 'works of fiction'.

'Provocative fiction(s)' is not a genre: it just means 'thought-provoking and/or emotive work(s) of fiction'.